# Javascript form value restriction

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a form which will store values in an empty array but the values must be between 0 to 5 and comma separated. the problem is it alerts if values is more than 5 but still stores the value in the array. I want it to alert and then restore the form value.

Here is my code:

```
<form name ="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="number" name="text" id="inputText" name="inputText" />
    <button onclick="pushData();">Insert</button>
    <p id="pText"></p>
</form>
```

And javascript:

```
function validateForm () {
    var form = document.forms["form1"]["inputText"].value;
    if(form <0 && form >= 6) {
        alert('value should must be between 0 to 5');
        return false;
    }
}

// create an empty array
var myArr = [];

function pushData() {
    // get value from the input text
    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;

    // append data to the array
    myArr.push(inputText);

    var pval = "";

    for(i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
        pval = pval + myArr[i];
    }

    // display array data
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "Grades: "  + pval ;

}
```

Comment: Sigh, this `form <0 && form >= 6` is never true.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (form <0 || form >= 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number):

> A number input is considered valid when empty and when a single number
>   is entered, but is otherwise invalid.

With this particular form element you may add min and max attributes so that the user must enter a value within a specified range. Therefore, the current contents of the OP's validateForm() function are superfluous. Additionally, that function has a problematic line of code:

```
if(form <0 && form >= 6) {
```

You cannot have a value that is both less than zero and greater than or equal to six.  Use instead a logical OR, i.e. "||" operator for the logic to work.

The following code allows for a user to select numeric values in the range that the OP specifies and then it displays them in a comma-separated format, as follows:

```js
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;
var pText = d.g('pText');
pText.innerHTML = "Grades: ";

var inputText = d.g("inputText"); 
var myArr = [];


function pushData() {
   var notrailingcomma = "";
   
   myArr.push(inputText.value);
   
   if (myArr.length > 1) {
     notrailingcomma = myArr.join(", ").trim().replace(/,$/g,"");
     pText.innerHTML = "Grades: " + notrailingcomma;   
   }
   else
   {
      pText.innerHTML += inputText.value;
   }   
}


d.forms["form1"].onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    pushData();
};
```

```css
p {
padding: 1em;
margin:1em;
background:#eeeeff;
color: #009;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<input type="number" id="inputText"  name="inputText"  min=0 max=5 value=0>

<button type="submit">Insert</button>

</form>
        
 <p id="pText"></p>
```

A couple of points with respect to the form:

- The OP's HTML has an error in the input field:  it has two names.  I dropped the one with a name of "text".
- I like what @thgaskell recommends with respect to changing "Insert" into a submit button, preventing the default action of submitting the form, and associating pushData with the form's onsubmit event.  So, I've modified the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may work better if you reorganize where the functions are being bound.

Event propagation order:

1. The button is clicked, and the value is pushed into the array.
2. The form's `submit` event triggers, and validates the values, but it's too late.

There are many ways to approach this one, but the simplest would be to call `pushData` at the end of your `validateForm`.

> Adjusted the condition, because there's no way for a number to
>   be less than `0` **AND** greater than or equal to `6` at the same time.
>
> Also added `event.preventDefault` to stop form submission.

**JavaScript**

```
function validateForm (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = document.forms["form1"]["inputText"].value;
  if (form < 0 || form > 5) {
    alert('value should must be between 0 to 5');
    return false;
  }
  pushData();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
  <input type="number" id="inputText" />
  <button type="submit">Insert</button>
  <p id="pText"></p>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pfjtqgv/)